Oracle apex change side menu icon color
I have a question is it posible to chnage the color of a icon in the side menu?
I can chnage this on my topmenu, but cannot change this in the same way in the side menu.
In the topmenu i have added this in the
image/class: fa-users-alt u-color-1-text and it works.
Alternativly is it ok to chnage the whole menu button.
side menu with icons
the top menu icons
